# How do I count meeting participants before adding another in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

**How do i count the total participants of a meeting before adding another and sending it?**

I've managed to automate calendar invites based on specific responses.

I now need to set a max number of participants and respond with a mail if the maximum number of participants for that meeting or event has been reached.

It seems to stay on "1" if i check the value.

This is as far as i've been able to come without reaching out for help on it.

```
Private Sub objNewMailItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)


Dim objMeetingInvitation As Outlook.MeetingItem
Dim objMeeting As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim objAttendees As Outlook.Recipients
Dim objAttendee As Outlook.Recipient
Dim lRequiredAttendeeCount, lOptionalAttendeeCount, lResourceCount As Long
Dim strMsg As String
Dim nPrompt As Integer


On Error Resume Next

Dim olMailItem As MailItem
Dim strAttachementName As String
Dim oRespond As Outlook.MailItem
Dim mesgBody As String
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oCalFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim sOldText As String
Dim sNewText As String
Dim iCalChangedCount As Integer
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
Set oApp = Outlook.Application
Dim nmSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Set nmSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oCalFolder = nmSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

        If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then

                    Set olMailItem = Item
                    Set objMeetingInvitation = Item
                    Set objMeeting = objMeetingInvitation.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
                    Set objAttendees = objMeetingInvitation.Recipients

                    lRequiredAttendeeCount = 0
                    lOptionalAttendeeCount = 0
                    lResourceCount = 0

                   'Count the required & optional attendees and resources, etc.


                    '===============================================================================================================
                    ' Please note...
                    '
                    '   I used mailto:jakes@******.co.za?subject=Yes,%20please%20include%20me&body=I%20would%20like%20to%20join
                    '   as a "mailto:" response
                    '
                    '===============================================================================================================


                        If InStr(olMailItem.Subject, "Testing the Calendar") > 0 Then
                        sOldText = "Test Calendar"

                            For Each objAttendee In objAttendees
                                If objAttendee.Type = olRequired Then
                                   lRequiredAttendeeCount = lRequiredAttendeeCount + 1
                                ElseIf objAttendee.Type = olOptional Then
                                   lOptionalAttendeeCount = lOptionalAttendeeCount + 1
                                ElseIf objAttendee.Type = olResource Then
                                   lResourceCount = lResourceCount + 1
                                End If
                            Next

                            If lRequiredAttendeeCount > 1 Then
                                MsgBox "Attendees on list too many :" & lRequiredAttendeeCount, vbOKOnly
                                Exit Sub
                            End If

                        Do
                            If Not (oCalFolder Is Nothing) Then
                                If (oCalFolder.DefaultItemType = olAppointmentItem) Then Exit Do

                            End If



                            'MsgBox ("Please select a calendar folder from the following list.")
                            'Set oCalFolder = GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
                            On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
                                Loop Until oCalFolder.DefaultItemType = olAppointmentItem
                                ' Loop through appointments in calendar, change text where necessary, keep count
                                iCalChangedCount = 0
                            For Each oAppt In oCalFolder.Items
                                If InStr(oAppt.Subject, sOldText) <> 0 Then
                                    Debug.Print "Changed: " & oAppt.Subject & " - " & oAppt.Start
                                    oAppt.Recipients.Add (olMailItem.SenderEmailAddress)
                                    'oAppt.Display
                                    oAppt.Save
                                    oAppt.Send
                                    iCalChangedCount = iCalChangedCount + 1
                                End If
                            Next
                            ' Display results and clear table
                            MsgBox (iCalChangedCount & " appointments have been updated. You have " & lRequiredAttendeeCount & "attendees.")

                        Set oAppt = Nothing
                        Set oCalFolder = Nothing
                        Exit Sub
                        End If


  ErrHandler:
        MsgBox ("Macro terminated.")



                        End If
                    Set Item = Nothing
                    Set olMailItem = Nothing

  End Sub
```

I've been able to count the participants with this but i'm lost trying to combine the two...

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim objMeetingInvitation As Outlook.MeetingItem
Dim objMeeting As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim objAttendees As Outlook.Recipients
Dim objAttendee As Outlook.Recipient
Dim lRequiredAttendeeCount, lOptionalAttendeeCount, lResourceCount As Long
Dim strMsg As String
Dim nPrompt As Integer

If TypeOf Item Is MeetingItem Then
   Set objMeetingInvitation = Item
   Set objMeeting = objMeetingInvitation.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
   Set objAttendees = objMeetingInvitation.Recipients
End If

lRequiredAttendeeCount = 0
lOptionalAttendeeCount = 0
lResourceCount = 0

'Count the required & optional attendees and resources, etc.
For Each objAttendee In objAttendees
     If objAttendee.Type = olRequired Then
        lRequiredAttendeeCount = lRequiredAttendeeCount + 1
     ElseIf objAttendee.Type = olOptional Then
        lOptionalAttendeeCount = lOptionalAttendeeCount + 1
     ElseIf objAttendee.Type = olResource Then
        lResourceCount = lResourceCount + 1
     End If
Next



'Double check the meeting invitation details
strMsg = "Meeting Details:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
 "Required Attendees: " & lRequiredAttendeeCount & vbCrLf & _
 "Optional Attendees: " & lOptionalAttendeeCount & vbCrLf & _
 "Resources: " & lResourceCount & vbCrLf & _
 "Duration: " & GetDuration(objMeeting) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
 "Are you sure to send this meeting invitation?"

nPrompt = MsgBox(strMsg, vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Double Check Meeting Invitation")

If nPrompt = vbYes Then
   Cancel = False
Else
   Cancel = True
End If


End Sub
```

Any ideas at all will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the question is too broad and could be split into at least three separate questions. Focusing on "How do I count the total participants of a meeting" without the adding and sending part.

I have to assume you run the code when a response arrives.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub objNewMailItems_ItemAdd_Test()
    ' first open up a response to a meeting invitation
    objNewMailItems_ItemAdd ActiveInspector.currentItem
End Sub


Private Sub objNewMailItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem

Dim objAttendees As Recipients
Dim objAttendee As Recipient

Dim lRequiredAttendeeCount As Long
Dim lOptionalAttendeeCount  As Long
Dim lResourceCount As Long

Dim possibleAttendees As Long

Dim limitedAtendees As Long

' For testing purposes
limitedAtendees = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the maximum number of invitations allowed", Default:="2")

'limitedAtendees = some maximum


' Kiss of death removed
'On Error Resume Next

If TypeOf Item Is MeetingItem Then

    ' Bypass one error only, for a specific purpose
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oAppt = Item.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
    ' Turn off bypass
    On Error GoTo 0

    If oAppt Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No associated appointment found."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set objAttendees = oAppt.Recipients
    'Debug.Print objAttendees.count

    lRequiredAttendeeCount = 0
    lOptionalAttendeeCount = 0
    lResourceCount = 0

    'Count the required & optional attendees and resources, etc.

    For Each objAttendee In objAttendees

        'Debug.Print objAttendee

        If objAttendee.Type = olRequired Then
            lRequiredAttendeeCount = lRequiredAttendeeCount + 1
        'ElseIf objAttendee.Type = olOptional Then
        '    lOptionalAttendeeCount = lOptionalAttendeeCount + 1
        'ElseIf objAttendee.Type = olResource Then
        '    lResourceCount = lResourceCount + 1
        End If

    Next

    If lRequiredAttendeeCount > limitedAtendees Then
        MsgBox "Invitations to Required Atendees: " & lRequiredAttendeeCount & vbCr & _
          "This is more than the limit of.......: " & limitedAtendees, vbOKOnly
    Else
        MsgBox "Invitations to Required Atendees: " & lRequiredAttendeeCount & vbCr & _
          "This is within the limit of...........: " & limitedAtendees, vbOKOnly
    End If

    If objAttendees.count > limitedAtendees Then
        MsgBox "Invitations to All Atendees..: " & objAttendees.count & vbCr & _
          "This is more than the limit of: " & limitedAtendees, vbOKOnly
    Else
        MsgBox "Invitations to All Atendees: " & lRequiredAttendeeCount & vbCr & _
          "This is within the limit of....: " & limitedAtendees, vbOKOnly
    End If

End If

ExitRoutine:
    Set oAppt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Edit 2071010

The code in the question points to a count of invitations but appears you need a count of responses.

```
Private Sub objNewMailItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

Dim objAppt As AppointmentItem
Dim objAttendee As Recipient

Dim lOrganizerAttendeeCount As Long
Dim lRequiredAttendeeCount As Long
Dim lOptionalAttendeeCount As Long
Dim lResourceCount As Long

Dim attendeeOrganizerNoneCount As Long
Dim attendeeAcceptedCount As Long
Dim attendeeTentativeCount As Long
Dim attendeeDeclinedCount As Long
Dim attendeeNotRespondedCount As Long

Dim invitedAttendees As Long
Dim respondingAttendees As Long

Dim uPrompt As String
Dim uTitle As String

Debug.Print
Debug.Print "Item.Class: " & Item.Class

'  26 - AppointmentItem
'
' Various MeetingItems
'  53 to 57
'  53 - should be the initial invitation
' 181 - Meeting Forward Notification
'  - with no response (0), the invited person counts as a "None" response

If Item.Class = 26 Then
    Set objAppt = Item

' tested
'   olMeetingResponsePositive
'    53
'   181
ElseIf Item.Class = olMeetingResponsePositive Or _
  Item.Class = olMeetingResponseTentative Or _
  Item.Class = olMeetingResponseNegative Or _
  Item.Class = 53 Or _
  Item.Class = 54 Or _
  Item.Class = 55 Or _
  Item.Class = 56 Or _
  Item.Class = 57 Or _
  Item.Class = 181 Then

    ' Bypass errors for a specific purpose
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objAppt = Item.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
    ' Turn error bypass off
    On Error GoTo 0

    If objAppt Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No appointment associated with the meeting response " & _
          vbCr & vbCr & Item.Subject
        Exit Sub
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "Item class " & Item.Class & " not recognized in this code. "
    Exit Sub

End If

For Each objAttendee In objAppt.Recipients

    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "Invitee name...: " & objAttendee.name

    'Count the invitations

    Debug.Print "Invitation Type: " & objAttendee.Type

    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/olmeetingrecipienttype-enumeration-outlook
    ' 0 = olOrganizer
    ' 1 = olRequired
    ' 2 = olOptional
    ' 3 = olResource

    Select Case objAttendee.Type

        Case 0
            lOrganizerAttendeeCount = lOrganizerAttendeeCount + 1

        Case 1
            lRequiredAttendeeCount = lRequiredAttendeeCount + 1

        Case 2
            lOptionalAttendeeCount = lOptionalAttendeeCount + 1

        Case 3
            lResourceCount = lResourceCount + 1

    End Select

    ' Count the responses

    Debug.Print "Response Status: " & objAttendee.MeetingResponseStatus

    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/olresponsestatus-enumeration-outlook
    ' 0 = "None" - This is what I get as the organizer
    ' 1 = "Organized"
    ' 2 = "Tentative"
    ' 3 = "Accepted"
    ' 4 = "Declined"
    ' 5 = "Not Responded"

    Select Case objAttendee.MeetingResponseStatus

        Case 0
             attendeeOrganizerNoneCount = attendeeOrganizerNoneCount + 1

        Case 1
            attendeeOrganizerNoneCount = attendeeOrganizerNoneCount + 1

        Case 2
            attendeeTentativeCount = attendeeTentativeCount + 1

        Case 3
            attendeeAcceptedCount = attendeeAcceptedCount + 1

        Case 4
            attendeeDeclinedCount = attendeeDeclinedCount + 1

        Case 5
            attendeeNotRespondedCount = attendeeNotRespondedCount + 1

    End Select

    Set objAttendee = Nothing

Next

invitedAttendees = lOrganizerAttendeeCount + lRequiredAttendeeCount + _
                    lOptionalAttendeeCount + lResourceCount

respondingAttendees = attendeeOrganizerNoneCount + attendeeAcceptedCount + _
                    attendeeTentativeCount + attendeeDeclinedCount + attendeeNotRespondedCount

' Display results
uTitle = "Attendees for " & objAppt.Subject

uPrompt = "Invitations:" & vbCr & _
  " " & lOrganizerAttendeeCount & " :Organizer" & vbCr & _
  " " & lRequiredAttendeeCount & " :Required" & vbCr & _
  " " & lOptionalAttendeeCount & " :Optional" & vbCr & _
  " " & lResourceCount & " :Resource" & vbCr & _
  " " & invitedAttendees & " : TOTAL" & vbCr & vbCr

uPrompt = uPrompt & " Responses:" & vbCr & _
  " " & attendeeOrganizerNoneCount & " :organizer none" & vbCr & _
  " " & attendeeAcceptedCount & " :accepts" & vbCr & _
  " " & attendeeTentativeCount & " :tentatives" & vbCr & _
  " " & attendeeDeclinedCount & " :declines" & vbCr & _
  " " & attendeeNotRespondedCount & " :no responses" & vbCr & _
  " " & respondingAttendees & " : TOTAL"

    MsgBox Prompt:=uPrompt, Title:=uTitle

ExitRoutine:
    Set objAppt = Nothing
    Set objAttendee = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I hear what you are saying. Let me break it down from your solution and then try it in sections. For now i've set it up to count folder items, and i've set a rule to move the responses into that folder in order to use the macro to keep count and automatically respond with a template.

Counting the attendees would be a much cleaner solution, maybe, if i'm brave enough, i'll attempt to remove cancellations automatically :-D

I will take another shot at it in a bit and come back.

Comment: @Jakes answer now includes a count of responses